# How can I prevent a page from going to the top every time a button with OnClick event is clicked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

How can I prevent a page from going back to the top every time a button is click? I still want to execute the code on the "OnClick" event for the button.

Example:

Almost all of our forms have a button on the bottom of the page which are suppose to bring some data back from the DB and populate some labes and textboxes located on the bottom of the page, when the button is click it takes user back to the top of the page. How can I prevent this from happening?

Any help will be really appreciate it.

Comment: Sounds like you want to make an AJAX request instead of a full post back?

Comment: Does your onClick return false ?

Comment: Technically it doesn't take the user back to the top of the page.  The page goes away when you submit a form.  What the user sees is a new page rendered from the server.

Comment: I see what you're saying. So, how can a prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Use [ASP.NET Ajax](http://www.asp.net/ajax), in particular the [UpdatePanel](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control/) control
2. Set [MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback.aspx) to `true` on page level or in web.config

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the OnClick event is handled on the server and not in javascript, the easiest thing is wrap the controls to be updated in an [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx) and have the update panel trigger on the button's click event.

Here is an example from Microsoft's documentation:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" 
            Text="Refresh Panel"
            runat="server" />
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" 
                   runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" 
                 UpdateMode="Conditional"
                 runat="server">
                 <Triggers>
                   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
                 </Triggers>
                 <ContentTemplate>
                 <fieldset>
                 <legend>UpdatePanel content</legend>
                 <%=DateTime.Now.ToString() %>
                 </fieldset>
                 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: What can I do if this button is inside a GridView or DataList?

Answer (score 2):

in your page declaration you can add MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" ie:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ... MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>
```

you can also put that in your web.config under system.web or declare it from codebehind Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback=true;

Comment: This creates an unpleasant "flicker" effect especially noticeable if the page is large or takes a long time to load and render.

Answer (score 0):

In the function handler for the button make sure you return `false`. You might be actually posting the page with those buttons rather than just doing something on the click event.